# Place not showing up on Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-custom-search

I'm trying to search for `Erna properties`. If you type it in Google search, the first result shows up the website. I tried searching for it under Google places API -

1. `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json`
2. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json`

However it didn't show up. Can someone help me with this problem? 
There is also another issue wherein if I search for it under Google's customsearch, it never shows the result which I apparently get as the first result under normal Google web search which apparently contains the website/

Answer (score 4):

I can see that this place exists in Google Maps:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Erna+Properties/@40.3618793,-74.2530876,11.54z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c231e71254bc01:0x18519e1bff73fee0!8m2!3d40.342263!4d-74.102175

However, indeed, the Places API cannot find it. I believe this is because the place was created in Google My Business as a Service Area Business. Unfortunately, the Places API autocomplete and searches don't work with Service Area Businesses. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to make SABs available in autocomplete and searches. You can see this feature request here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828187

Feel free to star the feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further notifications from Google.

In the meantime, if you need a place ID for Erna Properties, you have to use a Google My Business place ID finder located at

https://support.google.com/business/answer/7035772#place_id

I figured out that place ID of Erna Properties is `ChIJAbxUEucxwokR4P5z_xueURg`. You can use it with place details. E.g.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJAbxUEucxwokR4P5z_xueURg&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

[image]

I hope this helps!